# Expected behaviour of custom instance method sort

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, `list` objects implement a `sort` method taking the three arguments `cmp`, `key`, and `reverse`, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) (see note 8), the first two of which default to the value `None`, and the last defaulting to `False`.

Suppose one is interested in implementing a class providing an instance method named `sort` with the same signature, i.e., taking the same arguments, as `list.sort`. For `list.sort`, the `cmp` and `key` arguments may induce different orders on the list to be sorted and may therefore be incompatible.

My question is whether there is a best practice one should follow in implementing the instance method `sort` in the case where both `cmp` and `key` are different from `None`?

For clarity, consider the following example scenario:

```
class Table(object):

    """Stores data by rows."""

    def __init__(self, *rows):
        self._rows = list(rows)

    def sort(self, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False):
        """Sort table rows."""

        if cmp and key:
            # What behaviour would an experienced Python programmer
            # expect in this situation? Raise a ValueError? Prefer
            # one of cmp and key? Or is there no best practice here?
            raise ValueError('I am partial to raising a ValueError.')

        # The implementation could be more involved than pushing the
        # call to sort forward to self._rows, for instance if data was
        # stored by columns.
        self._rows.sort(cmp, key, reverse)
```

**Note:** The question raised here is not an issue in Python 3.6, where the argument `cmp` is not supported by `list.sort` ([source](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#lists)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the premise a little flawed here:

> For `list.sort`, the `cmp` and `key` arguments may induce different orders on the list to be sorted and may therefore be incompatible.

`cmp` and `key` aren't generally incompatible because they do different things. `key` defines how to map the members of the list to a value which they will be sorted by, and `cmp` defines how to determine the relative order of any two of those values. It's perfectly valid (though rarely a good idea) to use both:

```
>>> mylist = [(2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (7, 'seven')]
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda a:a[1], cmp=lambda a,b:ord(a[-1])-ord(b[-1]))
>>> mylist
[(3, 'three'), (7, 'seven'), (2, 'two')]
```

There I've sorted the list by the last letter of the second item. I could have used `cmp` or `key` individually to do the job (and the advice these days is to use `key`), but if I really want to, using both works just fine.

All that said, your example of making the sort method just a wrapper for sorting an internal list seems pretty trivial. Why do any validation at all if you want to match the functionality of the built-in `list.sort()`? Just pass everything straight through:

```
def sort(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._rows.sort(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Let me see if I understood you correctly. If both `cmp` and `key` are specified, the sorting works by first mapping the list, call it `X`, pointwise by `key` to a new list `Y`. Then `cmp` determines the order on `Y`, and `X` is ultimately sorted according to this order? As for the triviality of my example: the application I have in mind is not just a wrapper for sorting an internal list, but requires the implementation of a non-trivial algorithm. I was confused as to how one should proceed when both `cmp` and `key` were specified, being under the impression that they operated in isolation.

Comment: @Qeeko I don't know exactly how it's implemented internally, but yes, that's consistent with my understanding of how it logically works.

Comment: Yes, I was speaking conceptually. Thanks.